# How to Upload AASA (apple-app-site-association) file in third Party Domain (mydomain.app.link)

Tags: ios, swift, deep-linking, branch.io, ios-universal-links

I am using universal linking in my iOS application.
I have 2 domains for my app.

**1) [www.mydomain.com](http://www.mydomain.com)**

**2) mydomain.app.link (which is third-party domain, this domain is provided by branch.io)**

I have successfully uploaded AASA file in my first Domain and this is totally working fine
but I don't know how to upload AASA file in my second domain which  is **mydomain.app.link**

Answer (score 1):

A Branchster Here-

You do not need to manually create and upload the AASA file for your Branch App Link Domain.

Branch itself creates and hosts the AASA file for you when you check `Universal Links` on the Branch Dashboard's Configuration Section.

[image: iOS Redirects]

You can validate the hosted AASA file at - https://mydomain.app.link/apple-app-site-association

or you can also use the [AASA Validator](https://branch.io/resources/aasa-validator/).